# Adding a viewController as an argument in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a swift developer, but I need to edit a codebase in Objective-C...I need to add a `UIViewController` as an argument in the below method, so that I can pass in self when I call it.  Can anyone help me construct the method in Objective-C?

(I only need the argument in authenticate, not in silentlyAuthenticate).  My end goal is that I'm trying to implement `SafariViewController` instead of Pinterest SDK's current `openURL` log in.

Classes I'm editing:

https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk/blob/master/Pod/Classes/PDKClient.h
https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk/blob/master/Pod/Classes/PDKClient.m

My edits to code so far:

https://gist.github.com/gesabo/a29c015692c8d657cfe9c7fb1fc54707
https://gist.github.com/gesabo/bcf4d4f7b729e14a3d2dc9249bc8b54e

```
- (void)silentlyAuthenticateWithSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                                 andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;
{
    [self authenticateWithPermissions:nil silent:YES withSuccess:successBlock andFailure:failureBlock];
}

- (void)authenticateWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock
{
    [self authenticateWithPermissions:permissions silent:NO withSuccess:successBlock andFailure:failureBlock];
}

- (void)authenticateWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                             silent:(BOOL)silent
                        withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                         andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock
{
    __weak PDKClient *weakSelf = self;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you're asking - the change in .m file:

```
- (void)authenticateWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                     viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                        withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock  
                         andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock
{
    // use viewController
}
```

Or the same change in the second method:

```
- (void)authenticateWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                     viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                             silent:(BOOL)silent
                        withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                         andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock
{
    // use viewController
}
```

And in .h file the corresponding method declarations are also to be updated:

```
- (void)authenticateWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                     viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                        withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock  
                         andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;
```

and

```
- (void)authenticateWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                     viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                             silent:(BOOL)silent
                        withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                         andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;
```

Comment: thanks!  but then I'm getting an error on line 170 "no visible @interface for "PDKClient" declares the selector "AuthenticateWIthPermissions.withSuccessandFailure"?

Comment: It is not clear when you're trying to do. You can get help but some common ground is needed: could you push your test/demo project to Github somewhere?

Comment: I added 2 gists to my question with the code I've edited so far:  my goal is to (1) add a ViewController as an argument (2) then instantiate a SafariViewController using the OAuthURL, so that I can call `authenticateWithPermissions` inside a viewController and pass in .self (so that the authentication takes place inside in the app in SFVC, instead of the current openURL which takes the user outside of my app)

Comment: I think I'm getting what you want to archive. Let's fix warning on line 170 first. I have commented on your modified .m gist.

Comment: Thanks, I made those changes on the gist

Comment: I have just commented there. Let's continue discussion there on Github because SO doesn't favor extended discussions in comments.

Comment: I commented on the gist Stanislav, but marking the question answered here since you did answer my original question.

Comment: I have just read your report at pinterest/ios-pdk/issues/70 to understand your context, give me some time to look at PinterestSDK example. Also Github gists somehow do not send email notifications so please contact me via email that you can find on my Github page so that we can discuss this further.